# New header file not showed in Project Mode in Android Studio 3.1.1

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to learn a bit of Android development.
I've started a new project for a simple hello world and it works fine.

The project is essentially the default one + one more header file in the `cpp` folder,

However I can't see such `.cpp` in the project mode, can anyone suggest how to fix this?

(See picture below).

[image]

I've attempted to change some setting in `File > Project Structure` but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Maybe worth noticing that the header file isn't listed in the `CMakeLists.txt` at all.

```
# For more information about using CMake with Android Studio, read the
# documentation: https://d.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native library.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )

# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib} )
```

Comment: Apparently every time I add a new file (at least `.cpp`) I need to update the `CMakeLists.txt` manually accordingly, I can see a new source file now, but I can't see the `.h` yet. Please any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

According to the android doc:

> Known Issue: Android Studio currently shows you only the header files that have matching source files—even if you specify other headers in your CMake build script. See Issue #38068472

This means you need a pair `filename.h` and `filename.cpp`, you modify your `CMakeLists.txt` accordingly. The header file will be shown in project mode if it has a corresponding `.cpp` with the same name.

Reference:

https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code